# mySQL CASE THEN <something> ELSE <dont select>

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using mySQL query together with CASE statement in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * from places WHERE 
                        CASE WHEN
                            column1 > column2
                        THEN 
                            id > 100
                        WHEN 
                            column1 < column2
                        THEN
                            id < 100
                         ELSE
                            <DONT SELECT THE ROW>
                         END
```

I'm not sure how to Not select any rows if column1 = column2 (meaning we are in the ELSE branch). How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add impossible condition  `ELSE 0 = 1`. Another option I'm not 100% sure is not to put anything in `ELSE` - it must have default `ELSE NULL`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * from places WHERE 
                    CASE WHEN
                        column1 > column2
                    THEN 
                        id > 100
                    WHEN 
                        column1 < column2
                    THEN
                        id < 100
                    END
AND column1 != column2
```